# struct and class didSet procedures behaving differently

Tags: class, swift, struct, reference, didset

I've filed this as a radar report, but I'm not sure what they will do.

What I have, is a struct, and that struct is instantiated and aggregated by a class instance.

Since a struct is an object, it has setters and getters, as well as set/get observers.

I'm using these observers to re-index an array of the struct instances.

The deal is, that a struct has a "visible" flag (in my implementation). If that flag is turned off (set to false), then the container class needs to re-index all its structs, to remove the now-invisible (or now-visible) instance from the index.

So, the best way to do that, is, when I instantiate a struct instance, I hand it a reference to the container instance, and set up a didSet { myContainer.reIndex() } handler.

The problem is that structs and classes seem to behave differently. I suspect it's a value/reference issue.

In a class, the external value of the instance is set by the time didSet is called. This means that I can call an external object to re-index, and it will see the new value.

In a struct, this does not seem to be the case until after didSet is executed.

I'll include the playground that I submitted with the RADAR report.

My question is: Do you think structs should have setter/getter observers? Should they have setter/getter at all?

I do have a workaround. I call the indexer after changing the value. It's just not as graceful.

The playground (in the below code, see the different values emitted during the didSet handlers):

```
struct StructA
{
    let classBInstance:ClassB

    init ( inClassB:ClassB )
    {
        self.classBInstance = inClassB
        self.testProperty = 0
    }

    var testProperty:Int = -1
    {
        didSet
        {
            self.classBInstance.reactToSetStruct ( )
        }
    }
}

class ClassA
{
    let classBInstance:ClassB

    init ( inClassB:ClassB )
    {
        self.classBInstance = inClassB
        self.testProperty = 0
    }

    var testProperty:Int = -1
    {
        didSet
        {
            self.classBInstance.reactToSetClass ( )
        }
    }
}

class ClassB
{
    var structAInstance:StructA! = nil
    var classAInstance:ClassA! = nil

    init()
    {
        self.structAInstance = StructA ( inClassB:self )
        self.classAInstance = ClassA ( inClassB:self )
    }

    func doSetStruct()
    {
        println ("Before Set: Struct Property Value is \(self.structAInstance.testProperty)")
        self.structAInstance.testProperty = 1
        println ("After Set: Struct Property Value is \(self.structAInstance.testProperty)")
    }

    func doSetClass()
    {
        println ("Before Set: Class Property Value is \(self.classAInstance.testProperty)")
        self.classAInstance.testProperty = 1
        println ("After Set: Class Property Value is \(self.classAInstance.testProperty)")
    }

    func reactToSetStruct()
    {
        println ("Struct Value is now \(self.structAInstance.testProperty)")
    }

    func reactToSetClass()
    {
        println ("Class Value is now \(self.classAInstance.testProperty)")
    }
}

let classTest:ClassB = ClassB()

classTest.doSetStruct()
classTest.doSetClass()
```

Comment: Well, maybe stating the obvious, but I agree, it looks like a bug in the struct handling. `oldValue` seems to be correctly set, but the new value should (according to the spec) be set _before_ didSet is called.

Comment: I agree, but I have a nasty feeling that Apple will respond by removing setters and getters from structs. Swift is a swiftly-moving target. Each beta is bringing in pretty massive language changes.

Comment: @MAGSHARE in the future please don't put tags in your question titles e.g. "Swift: ...question..." etc. It's considered noise since it doesn't help people search when you've already added the language tag.

Comment: Done. Also, just FYI, the issue is a closed RADAR report (18048502). It's sorted.